# Debugging in DEV-C++

Tags: c, debugging, runtime-error, dev-c++

How to use a debugger in DEV C++? I am finding problems resolving run-time errors in my C code written in DEV C++. How can the debugger help me resolve the run-time errors?

Comment: see this link (http://eilat.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/cis1_5/HowToDebug.htm)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are using a project.

Then go to `Project Options - Compiler - Linker` and set `Generate debugging information` to "yes", and make sure you are not using any optimization options (they're not good for debug mode). Also check the Parameters tab, make sure you don't have any optimization options (like -O2 or -O3, but -O0 is ok because it means no optimization) or strip option (-s).
After that, do a full rebuild (`Ctrl-F11`), then set breakpoint(s) where you want the debugger to stop (otherwise it will just run the program). To set a breakpoint on a line, just click on the gutter (the gray band on the left), or press `Ctrl-F5`.

Now you are ready to launch the debugger, by pressing `F8` or clicking the debug button. If everything goes well, the program will start, and then stop at the first breakpoint. Then you can step through the code, entering function calls, by pressing `Shift-F7` or the "step into" button, or stepping over the function calls, by pressing `F7` or the "next step" button. You can press `Ctrl-F7` or the "continue" button to continue execution till the next breakpoint. At any time, you can add or remove breakpoints.

When the program stopped at a breakpoint and you are stepping through the code, you can display the values of various variables in your program by putting your mouse over them, or you can display variables and expressions by pressing `F4` or the "add watch" button and typing the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue Although selecting the break points and select debug, debugging not working. I solved the problem as below:

- Be sure that project is opened.
- Display the project panel:
  View>Project /Class Browser, Select Debug tab from the project panel
- Set the base compiler:
  Project > Project Options > Compiler > Linker
  select the base compiler as “TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64 bit Debug”
  Set the “Generate debugging information” as YES
- Execute > Rebuild
- To debug:
  Execute > Toggle Breakpoint, then set the breakpoints.
  Execute > Debug
  Also check that at the menu bar base compiler is displayed as “TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64 bit Debug”

After selecting rebuild if directly breakpoints are set without selecting Toggle BreakPoints debugging is not started. Before selecting debug, selecting Toggle Breakpoint and then setting breakpoints solved the debug problem in my case.